# Compare Between Two Nested List With Different Index Amount

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have two nested list :

```
data1 = [["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381], ["tr4", 1200, 6798381]]

data2 = [["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid1"], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid2"], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381, "vid3"], ["tr3", 1200, 6798381, "vid4"]]

data2_but_same_index = [["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381], ["tr3", 1200, 6798381]]
```

and then i will compare between them but only in 3 first index. because when it return true it will take the fourth index in data2 list.

the return i expect when the amount of index is the same (compare data1 and data2_but_same_index)

```
data1 = [["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381], ["tr4", 1200, 6798381]]

data2 = [["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid1"], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid2"], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381, "vid3"], ["tr3", 1200, 6798381, "vid4"]]

data2_but_same_index = [["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381], ["tr3", 1200, 6798381]]

for x in data1 :
  if x in data2_without_vid :
    print("true")
  else :
    print("false")
```

the output will return :

```
true
true
true
false
```

i hope i can compare data_1 and data_2 like that, but the return is fourth index(if true) for each list inside data_2 list (vid1/vid2/vid3/vid4)

*Update data* :

data1 = [["tr1", 1001, 6798381],["tr1", 1001, 6798381],["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381], ["tr4", 1200, 6798381]]

*Update data new* :
data1 = [["tr3", 1200, 6798381], ["tr1", 1001, 6798381],["tr1", 1001, 6798381],["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381], ["tr4", 1200, 6798381]]

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the two lists and map the sub-lists to the `operator.eq` function for comparisons. Since `map` stops the iterations when any of the input sequences runs out, the fourth item of the second sub-lists would not be included in the comparisons:

```
from operator import eq

for a, b in zip(data1, data2):
    print(all(map(eq, a, b)) and b[3])
```

This outputs:

```
vid1
vid2
vid3
False
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBBCoMwFET3OcWQVQJZmERaW@hJxEVEpQE1MYRCe/nURrqy9i/f4zPD@Ge8u1lXPqQ0BDfB@T6Y6ALs5F2I6BdCOhONxA11TWOQVEAWRSFwOl8qXclG4B9XH672vNzxJgepwyAB@rCdpEeBm1f0KHjz@uv1b1/StQgZ1gWMQAs742U9yxMI5IL8SrCeD3aOzIwjm4xn/SLyA@cwc4e21g1P6Q0)

Comment: when i add "false" data in data 1, the output will all false and just return 4rows, it should be the amount is the same with index amount in data1

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "add 'false' data in data 1" and "the amount is the same with index amount in data1". Please clarify by updating your question with a sample input and an expected output for the scenario you're trying to illustrate.

Comment: add item inside list data_1, where the data will return false, ex : ["tr13", 2000, 777777]. it will be return false, because that data not in data_2. OK i will update the question too

Comment: i have update the question. try change data1 with :
data1 = [["tr1", 1001, 6798381],["tr1", 1001, 6798381],["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381], ["tr4", 1200, 6798381]]

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the equivalent size slices:

```
for x1, x2 in zip(data1, data2):
    print(x1 == x2[: len(x1)])
```

---

```
True
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `data2_without_vid` skipping `vids`

```
data2_without_vid = [x[:-1] for x in data2]

print(data2_without_vid)
#output

[['tr1', 1000, 6798381],
 ['tr1', 1000, 6798381],
 ['tr2', 1200, 6798381],
 ['tr3', 1200, 6798381]]
```

Now, comp[are as you were doing:

```
for x in data1 :
  if x in data2_without_vid :
    print("true")
  else :
    print("false")

#output
true
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
data2_dict = {(item[0], item[1], item[2]): item[3] for item in data2}

for x in data1:
    key = (x[0], x[1], x[2])
    if key in data2_dict:
        print(data2_dict[key])
    else:
        print("false")
```

Updated:

```
data2_dict = {(item[0], item[1], item[2]): item[3] for item in data2}

for x in data1:
    key = (x[0], x[1], x[2])
    if key in data2_dict:
        print(data2_dict[key])
        # Remove the key from data2_dict to prevent reuse
        del data2_dict[key]
    else:
        print("false")
```

Comment: the output :
false
false
vid1
false --> should be vid2 (["tr1", 1000, 6798381])
vid3
false

Answer (score 0):

Slice data2 to 3 first index:

```
data1 = [["tr1", 1001, 6798381],["tr1", 1001, 6798381],["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381], ["tr4", 1200, 6798381]]
data2 = [["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid1"], ["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid2"], ["tr2", 1200, 6798381, "vid3"], ["tr3", 1200, 6798381, "vid4"]]

print(*[x in [i[:3] for i in data2] for x in data1], sep='\n')

# False
# False
# True
# True
# True
# False
```

**Update #1:**

```
for i, x in enumerate(data1):
    print(data2[i-2][-1] if x in [d[:3] for d in data2] else False)

# False
# False
# vid1
# vid2
# vid3
# False
```

**Update #2:**

```
data1 = [
    ["tr1", 1002, 6798381],
    ["tr1", 1001, 6798381],
    ["tr1", 1001, 6798381],
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381],
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381],
    ["tr2", 1200, 6798381],
    ["tr4", 1200, 6798381],
    ["tr5", 1200, 6798381]
]

data2 = [
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid1"],
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid2"],
    ["tr2", 1200, 6798381, "vid3"],
    ["tr3", 1200, 6798381, "vid4"],
    ["tr4", 1200, 6798381, "vid5"]
] 
  
m = False
for x in data1:
    if x in (temp := [d[:3] for d in data2]):
        i, m = (temp.index(x,1), False) if m else (temp.index(x), True)
        print(data2[i][-1])
    else: print(m)

# False
# False
# False
# vid1
# vid2
# vid3
# vid5
# False
```

Comment: can you return the vid1/vid2/vid3/vid4/ instead of True ?

Comment: its almost done, but i get bug in your code when i using update data new. i have add the update data. the result not match when i adding this data.